# R4DS error comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter

In R4DS Section 3.6, the authors present the following code:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = class)) + 
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mpg, class == "subcompact"), se = FALSE)
```

which causes the following error

```
Error in class == "subcompact" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I assume it worked when the authors wrote it, as they have a nice plot illustrating the results.

What is happening and how do I fix it? (R 3.3.2 on OS X)
Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `filter()` function comes from the `dplyr` package. Be sure you've loaded it before running those lines. Otherwise, you're running a comparison with `class()`, the built-in function, rather than `mpg$class`.

Comment: Thank you. I have library(tidyverse)

Comment: oops. I have<code>library(tidyverse)</code> in my .Rprofile file, so it it loaded very early, and the console log doesn't indicate any conflicts

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ran `R --no-init-file` and then entered `library(tidyverse)` at the command line. I got a conflict message with `stats` for the `filter` function.  Now the code works fine.  It appears the order of the tidyverse load makes a difference.

Comment: Also make sure you dont have a typo in your variable name. For example, even if dplyr is loaded, if you dont have a column named class, you will get this error

Comment: @JHowlX your comment saved me! I had a capitalization typo that was throwing me off.

Answer (score 17):

You probably had another package with a function (filter) loaded and masking dplyr filter

quick and dirty fix:

```
dplyr::filter()
```

instead of

```
filter()
```

Comment: Seems like the more rigorous fix here, since it uses precisely the desired function!

Comment: Great answer and I actually prefer fully defining the function being used .

Answer (score 2):

use `{dplyr}`

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = class)) +
  geom_smooth(
    data = filter(mpg, class == "subcompact"),
    se = FALSE)
```